# Does Evernote update when installed under Wine?

Tags: wine, update-manager, evernote

I am considering to install Ubuntu on my PC. Evernote is an essential, irreplaceable app for me, & I only use the desktop client because all my notes are local. I learned that Evernote for Windows can be installed under Wine & while some people have hit glitches others have reported to have no probs. Assuming a no probs situation, do the updates that the Evernote team put out come through when using EN under Wine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Evernote will auto-update even under Wine. In fact, checking for and downloading a new version, installing and restarting Evernote happens just as under Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have 2 more questions about EN under Wine: 1) after installing wine do I need to download EN or can I use the Windows version already on my PC, 2) if I need to re-download, will EN under Wine use my existing EN database with existing notes?

Comment: 1) Better start with a fresh copy downloaded from the Evernote site. Even easier is to install Playonlinux, and install Evernote through that. (you will still need to download a copy of Evernote though). 2) Yes. If a re-install finds a notes database, it will use it, otherwise, you will be presented with a screen where you can log into Evernote using your existing account, and download all your notes.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that **Evernote auto-update does not work on Wine anymore** (at least that's what I can observe in my case, for **Evernote 5.8.x** - and 5.7.x, as far as I can remember). As you might expect, the solution is to uninstall your current version and install the new one.

It looks pretty straightforward, but sometimes you might stumble upon an issue of not being able to install the newest Evernote version after uninstalling the previous one. The error that occurs is basically saying, that you cannot install Evernote because it's already installed for another user and it's only one copy that is allowed to be installed at the same time.

If so, after uninstalling current Evernote, run:

```
grep "with upgrade" ~/.wine/drive_c/users/YOUR_USERNAME/Temp/EvernoteSetup.log
```

You will get a bunch of records like:

```
[02/14/2015 14:53:41] Located product {????????-????-????-????-????????????} with upgrade code {????????-????-????-????-????????????}.
[02/14/2015 15:02:53] No products with upgrade code {XXXXXXXX-????-????-????-????????????} found.
```

Try to find the most recent one (notice the date information) and copy the ID/string marked `XXXXXXXX` above (it would look something like `EC4A382C`).

Then **reverse** it (to get e.g. `C283A4CE`) and find a record in Wine's registry containing that ID/string (you can find Wine's registry in a file `/home/YOUR_USERNAME/.wine/system.reg`). The record would look like this (notice the `C283A4CE` string at the end of the path):

```
[Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Installer\\UpgradeCodes\\C283A4CE] 1216443328
```

Then, you just have to delete it (just that line, nothing more) and save the file. Bare in mind to back up `system.reg` file to restore it if something go wrong.

Although the solution looks kind of complicated, it works for me every time whenever I cannot update Evernote automatically via auto-update feature. :)

Also, you will notice that when trying to download Evernote's installer from official website, you get an information that Evernote is not available for Linux operating system. In such case, change your user-agent information via some user-agent related plugin available for your browser (like [User Agent Overrider](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/user-agent-overrider/) for Firefox), to pretend that you are on Windows OS.

*Marginal notes*: You could notice that for the latest versions of Evernote (especially for 5.8.3 and newer) there is a problem with note titles being invisible. There is a quick and easy fix for that - just issue `winetricks -q riched20` command ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/579218/171942)).

Comment: Also, bear in mind that the newest version of Evernote, namely 5.9.1, does not work on Wine as expected - there are major problems with notes browsing and editing ([more info](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39335)). Use previous version instead - e.g. 5.8.13.