# Evernote with wine. Titles of notes invisible

Tags: lubuntu, wine, evernote

I run Evernote 5.8.1.6061 in Wine under Lubuntu 14.04.
The title of the notes are not visible, I attached a picture of the situation.

How can I fix it? It's only since I upgraded to the newer version of Evernote, unfortunately I don't remember the number of the old version.

Is it maybe a font that's not installed on my os, or what could be the reason?

[image: pic]

Comment: Did you install corefonts? `winetricks corefonts`?

Comment: yes, I did. 
$winetricks corefonts
Executing w_do_call corefonts
corefonts already installed, skipping

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install `riched20`:

```
winetricks -q riched20
```

Comment: This did the trick for me. Could you tell me how you found out about this? Thanks!

Comment: I just tried out that fix got this [gist - output](https://gist.github.com/178d322f362381601eea.git) , in short , Downloading `http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/6/A/E6A04295-D2A8-40D0-A0C5-241BFECD095E/W2KSP4_EN.EXE failed`